# How to highlight a JSON file with a copy option in react application?

Tags: reactjs, highlight

I want to highlight a JSON file with a copy option in a JSON for the child. Child component code as below.

The below code gives an inline code highlight below. I want to show it as a code block. and users can copy the JSON file.
[image]

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Card } from "antd";
import Highlight from 'react-highlight'


const ResponsesDataView = React.memo((props) => {
 
 return (
   <>
     <Card size="small">
     <Highlight language="json">
     {JSON.stringify(props.jsonData)}
   </Highlight>
     </Card>
   </>
 );
});

export default ResponsesDataView
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Beautify the the `json` with `JSON.stringify(jsonData, null, 4)`
2. Use `textarea` to display the data with `readOnly` and `value` prop.
3. Use `useRef` to handle the highlighting and copying operations.

Your `ResponsesDataView` will look something like this

```
import { useRef, memo, useCallback } from "react";
import styles from "./Json.module.css";

const ResponsesDataView = memo((props) => {
  const { data } = props;
  const txtarea = useRef(null);

  const copyToClipboard = useCallback(() => {
    txtarea.current.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
  }, [txtarea]);
  const selectTextAreaValue = useCallback(() => {
    txtarea.current.select();
  }, [txtarea]);
  return (
    <div className={styles.areaContainer}>
      <div className={styles.btnContainer}>
        <button className={styles.copyBtn} onClick={selectTextAreaValue}>
          Select All
        </button>
        <button className={styles.copyBtn} onClick={copyToClipboard}>
          Copy
        </button>
      </div>
      <textarea
        className={styles.txtArea}
        ref={txtarea}
        readOnly
        value={JSON.stringify(data ? data : {}, null, 4)}
      ></textarea>
    </div>
  );
});

export default ResponsesDataView;
```

Here is a working [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-worker-lqr87)